# Override Alembic Revision ID Function

Tags: python

Is there anyway to override the revision id generated by alembic? The random ids have proven to a lot more hurt than help, and I really want to switch to a timestamp based approach that I've used in the past without fail.

I managed to find this, but I'm not sure of the smartest way to monkey patch it and whether the change would propagate to everything else as needed.

https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/src/efecc6c178d7b62f3d5ee35f2bf51ab79d310cdd/alembic/util.py?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default#util.py-253

Comment: there is also mention of `rev_id` here: http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/commands.html#alembic.command.merge AND http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/api/commands.html#alembic.command.revision, if rev_id is passed in it just uses the passed in rev_id string also see `_revision_illegal_chars`  and `alembic.script.base.generate_revision`  replacing a uuid4 string with something like epoch time seems doable?